# asp.net core mvc . having two (index) method with same name error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = _context.Properties.Where(x => x.isAvailable == true && x.isSpecialOffer == false ).ToList();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var img = _context.Pictures.Where(x => x.PropertyId == item.PropertyId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (item.pictures == null) item.pictures = new List<Picture>();
            item.pictures.Add(img);

        }
       return View(result);
    }


    ////     search functionality
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(String PropertySearch)
    {

        ViewData["GetPropertyDetail"] = PropertySearch;
        var properyquery = from x in _context.Properties select x;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertySearch))
        {
            properyquery = properyquery.Where(x => x.PropertyTitle.Contains(PropertySearch) || x.Ppurpose.Contains(PropertySearch) || x.PropertyType.Contains(PropertySearch));
        }
        return View(await properyquery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

This is the View where i call the function

|
        Clear Search

for the purpose of search functionality i added the second method of (INDEX) but it gives me error (because by default the route goes to the second search function while it needs to land on the first method by default) when i execute the application, because i have already have another index which by default fetches all the record from another model. please help me how to solve it?

Comment: Could you please share the View code from where you're calling the Index Methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can make one method that way:

```
public IActionResult Index(string? PropertySearch)
{
    if(PropertySearch == null)
    {
        var result = _context.Properties.Where(x => x.isAvailable == true && x.isSpecialOffer == false ).ToList();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var img = _context.Pictures.Where(x => x.PropertyId == item.PropertyId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (item.pictures == null) item.pictures = new List<Picture>();
            item.pictures.Add(img);
        }

        return View(result);
    }
    else //search functionality here
    {
        ViewData["GetPropertyDetail"] = PropertySearch;
        var properyquery = from x in _context.Properties select x;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertySearch))
        {
            properyquery = properyquery.Where(x => x.PropertyTitle.Contains(PropertySearch) || x.Ppurpose.Contains(PropertySearch) || x.PropertyType.Contains(PropertySearch));
        }
        return View(await properyquery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpPost] for your Search Method.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(String PropertySearch)
{

    ViewData["GetPropertyDetail"] = PropertySearch;
    var properyquery = from x in _context.Properties select x;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertySearch))
    {
        properyquery = properyquery.Where(x => x.PropertyTitle.Contains(PropertySearch) || x.Ppurpose.Contains(PropertySearch) || x.PropertyType.Contains(PropertySearch));
    }
    return View(await properyquery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
}
```